# Iterate all the rows of data frame and create new objects from its data

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with multiple columns and I want to create a JSON for each row in the data frame with values of specific columns.

Say, I have a data frame `df1` with columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`.

I am trying to create a JSON structure

```
{
   "source_id": df1.C,
   "target_id": df1.G,
   "time_of_creation": 123456789123
}
```

I am currently looping through each row using df1.rdd.toLocalIterator

Please let me know if there is a better approach

Comment: So you want to create `list` of `json` (one per row)? Or you want to create pyspark data frame, with a single column in `json` format (one row one `json`) or you want to convert the whole data frame into single `json` file?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I want to create a list of JSON (one per row). Because this list is being used as an input to another rest request (POST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_json` and `named_struct`:

```
df1.show()
+---+---+
|  C|  G|
+---+---+
| c1| g1|
+---+---+

result = df1.selectExpr("""
    to_json(
        named_struct(
            'source_id', C,
            'target_id', G,
            'time_of_creation', current_timestamp()
        )
    ) output_json
""")

result.show(20,0)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|output_json                                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"source_id":"c1","target_id":"g1","time_of_creation":"2021-01-02T14:12:19.612Z"}|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this output to another String variable? Because I basically want to create a list of JSON (one per row) as that list will be used as an input to another rest request (POST).

Comment: @Divakar you can use `jsonlist = result.rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()`

Comment: I was asked not to use "collect()" or "toLocalIterator()" as it is not best use of spark infrastructure in computing in parallel.  Please correct me, if my understanding is incorrect about "collect" brings all the records into driver and hence we are effectively processing them sequentially.

Comment: @Divakar you said you want to collect a list, so you need to do collect in order to bring all the records which have been processed back to the driver. Other operations are done in parallel, but the final step must involve collect in order to get the list you wanted back into the driver.